# What is document in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

as we all know document in javascript is an object.
If we type `window` or `this` in browser console it shows document is object contained inside window object of browser.

[IMG : window object containing document object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOpme.jpg)

if we type `document` it should show methods or properties of document object
but instead it shows source code of current page.

[IMG : when we type document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxSbC.jpg)

so, what is document actually ?

Comment: A lot of resources on the web for this question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document

Comment: That’s not the source code, that’s the DOM tree. Note that the exact display of objects logged in the console isn’t standardized yet; the current [draft](//console.spec.whatwg.org/#optimally-useful-formatting) just says _“An object with **optimally useful formatting** is an implementation-specific, potentially-interactive representation of an object judged to be maximally useful and informative.”_. The “optimally useful formatting” for `document`, in this specific console implementation, happens to look like a tree of HTML elements and other representations (such as `#document`).

Answer (score 2):

You're being confused by the fact that your dev tools represents the `document` element as the source tree (like it would for, say, a div you query with `document.querySelector("div")`).

But `document` (aka `window.document`) is just a [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) object.

Answer (score -1):

Every web page resides inside a browser window which can be considered as an object.

A Document object represents the HTML document that is displayed in that window. The Document object has various properties that refer to other objects which allow access to and modification of document content.

Link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_html_dom.htm

Ok this is ok